# Runtime Error "Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine"

Tags: perl

I have an array @jobs that contains 1 or more strings, but when I run the following code I get a runtime error "Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call at /home/xa341d/bin/hourly.pl line 32"

```
elsif (@jobs > 0) {
    my $my_jobs = "";
    my $i;

   for ($i = 0; i <= $#jobs; i++) {
       my $temp = $jobs[$i];
       $my_jobs += "-j $temp ";
   }

   print "my_jobs = $my_jobs\n";
    open $alOut, "/home/zn035b/bin/autorep2.pl $my_jobs -l 0 | grep `date \"+%m/%d/%Y\"` | sort -k 3,3|" or die "Can't open: $!";
}
```

does anyone know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Perl programmer would write that foreach loop as:

```
foreach my $job (@jobs) {
  $my_jobs .= "-j $job ";
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
$my_jobs .= "-j $_ " foreach @jobs;
```

C-style for loops are rarely used in Perl. And for good reason. A foreach loop is usually far easily to understand.

You could also do it with map:

```
my $jobs = join ' ', map { "-j $_" } @jobs;
```

Comment: Being more of a C-style programmer and not having much experience in perl I naturally went with C-style, this way makes sense and simplifies the whole thing.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the top of the script.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

You'll see that you're using `i` instead of `$i` in the loop, and also `+=` instead of `.=` which should be used for concatenation. `+=`, on the other hand, adds numeric value of the right side (which is 0, since "-j" is not a number) to the left side.

That said, I failed to get the "non-lvalue sub" message out of this code so you probably should provide more info or at least tell us what `line 32` is.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a variable sigil here: `for ($i = 0; $i <= $#jobs; i++)`. Without the `$` sigil `i` is treated as a subroutine name.

Also, this bit is likely wrong:

```
 $my_jobs += "-j $temp ";
```

As  `$my_jobs` is a string you should be using the `.=` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the for loop like this
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#jobs; $i++)

Then it will be ok.
You have missed the $ sign for variable i.